# Server-sent events with automatic reconnect (Spring WebFlux client)

Tags: spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I have a server dispatching server-sent events. When I use a browser-based client, everthing works as expected including automatic reconnect.

My problem is when I use the following Spring WebFlux based client application, everything works expect automatic reconnect:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("/register/")
         .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.newConnection()))
        .build();
ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {
};

Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.get()
        .uri("/client-id")
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(type)
        .repeat();

eventStream.subscribe(...)
```

My question: how can I reproduce the 'automatic reconnect' feature built into the browsers?

(I thought that `repeat()` will do it but unfortunatelly not: when the server goes down, a `reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response` exception is thrown in the client and it does not try to reconnect.)

Comment: I think you could try to use one of the `retry()` methods instead `repeat()`: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#retry--.
The `retryBackoff` may be neat: this would avoid to flood the server if ever lots of clients are trying to reconnect at the same tim.

Comment: `retry()` seems to work, thanks. It may be acceptable as an answer as well ;)